# Javascript: explictely ignore variables without esling warning about it

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have a code like this:

```
const [contract, _customer, _payment] = await Promise.all([
    api.signup.contract.sign(...),
    api.signup.update(...), 
    api.payment.update(...),
]);
```

And eslint is complaining because of

```
  118:15  warning  '_customer' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  118:26  warning  '_payment' is assigned a value but never used   @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

I though that prefixing the var with `_` was enought to explicetly ignore the var (meaning it's not a mistake)

What would be the best way avoid this issue?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but I think this begs the follow-up of why assign it at all if you don’t use it?

Comment: Don't destructure them? `const [contract] = ...`

Comment: No dumb question at all, it's just to make it clear that It's not an error, that I want to explicitly ignore that value even though it is begin returned

Comment: IMO, shutting off the warning will not change anything to your code quality... Not definining variables that are never used will. Would you explain your use case of having those variables for no reasons?

Comment: To tell that it is not a mistake, you could explicitely shut the error with a comment. `/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */` or is it `/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */`

Comment: sure, please read the comment above yours

Comment: You can ignore a return value by... ignoring it, now you are setting a variable with the returned value. Nothing ignored in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making eslint ignore variables starting with an `_` for the purposes of no-unused-vars tests is a [configurable option](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern):

> ```
> no-unused-vars: ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]
> ```

… however, in this case since you only use the *first* value, simply don't destructure the second and third:

```
const [contract] = await Promise.all([ //...
```

Comment: Just as a note: for a more general case, it *might* make sense to destructure three variables but only use one. If you're using an iterator, then `const [x, _y, _z] = it` will advance the iterator with three positions and maybe you want that - get just the first value but pull and discard the other ones ` const [x, , , ] = it` can do the same - pull `x` and assign it, then pull two more and discard it. But it might not be readable. It particular, it might not be clear how many values are taken. `[x]` and `[x,]` are the same -they take one. any extra comma pulls another. Naming them is clearer.